# Computations modulus a polynomial

Tags: finite-groups, multiplicative-order

Let $\lambda$ be in $\mathbb F_{p^\ell}\setminus \{0\}$ where $p$ is prime and $\ell \in \mathbb N_{\ge 1}$, and $j,k$ be three integers.

In order to calculate the multiplicative order of $X+\lambda$ in $(\mathbb F_{p^\ell}/(X^t))^*$ (which I know is equal to $p^\delta\mathrm{ord}(\lambda)$ where $\delta$ is such that $p^{\delta-1}<t\leqslant p^\delta$), I need to prove that there exists $S\in \mathbb F_{p^\ell}[X]$ such that $S(0)=0$, such that

> $$(X+\lambda)^{jp^k}=\lambda^{jp^k}+j\lambda^{(j-1)p^k}X^{p^k}(1+S(X)).$$

I try to use Newton's binomial theorem, but then I am stuck with proving that

$$\binom {jp^k}{p^k}=j$$

and

$$\binom {jp^k}{x}=0\in \mathbb F_{p^\ell}$$

if $p^k$ does not divide $x$.

Am I going the wrong way ? How should I prove this result ?

Comment: What is the original problem; i.e. what do you actually want to know about the order of $X + \lambda$ modulo $X^t$?

Comment: @RaviFernando I edited to add context about what is the original problem.